# Avoiding object saving in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

For my LINQ object Foo, I want to have a "before-and-after" state bracketing my object mutation (coming from an ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel() call as it happens). My idea was to copy the pre-mutation properties from the attached instance into a new unattached instance. Then I'd be able to make the updates in the attached instance and compare their values versus those in the unattached instance. Like so:

```
Foo real = context.Foos.First(aFoo => aFoo.ID == id)
Foo old = new Foo();
old.Bar = real.Bar;
old.Baz = real.Baz;
SomeSortOfUpdate(real);
if ( !real.Bar.Equals(old.Bar) || real.Baz.Equals(old.Baz) ) {
   LogChanges(old, real);
}
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Here's the problem: the object referenced by "Foo old" is getting saved (inserted) during `context.SubmitChanges()`. I traced this back to the assignment of properties that were LINQ-to-SQL associations.

So, for example, if Baz was a table-backed L2S-generated type, including `old.Baz = real.Baz` would cause a SQL insert for `old` in addition to any SQL update for `real`. Removing it (yet keeping `old.Bar`) makes things work as I expect.

I'm guessing that this is because the Foo.Baz assignment makes a link between Foo and Baz in the saveable object graph. Since `real` is getting saved, LINQ also walks all of the associated objects and looks for changes. `real.Baz` isn't itself changed, but it has a new association to `old`, which isn't yet saved and so gets caught up in the `SubmitChanges` call.

Is there any way I can *prevent* objects in the graph from being saved?

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct. Your assignments are establishing links.

You can modify the generated code to not do this (or write your own). But this means you have to live without auto-generated entity classes. I personally consider this to be unacceptable.

Why don't you serialize the pre-image object into a dictionary? Or copy its property values into a custom DTO class?

From your code I can tell that you want the old values to do change logging. You can do that using

```
DataContext.GetTable<T>().GetModifiedMembers(entity)
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder what this would do

```
 var old = (Foo)real;
```

I'm wondering if the instance itself is creating the connection

Comment: No, that just makes another reference to the same instance. It would not serve my purposes for determining the differences between the old and new states.